# Spring Boot integration test can't find configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit5

I have a simple Spring Boot application, consisting only of this class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I want to test whether the application starts.  That test looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceIT {

    @Test
    public void testContextLoads() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

When I run this test from my IDE (IntelliJ), it passes.  This is the expected behavior.

When I run it from the command line (`mvn integration-test`), I get the following failure:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

I'm using the following versions:

- Java: 14
- Maven: 3.6.0
- spring-boot: 2.3.4.RELEASE
- junit-jupiter: 5.6.2 (I'm not using JUnit 4)
- maven-failsafe-plugin: 3.0.0.M5

Any ideas as to why this fails on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried rolling back the version of `maven-failsafe-plugin` to `3.0.0.M4` and the test passed from the command line.  Therefore this appears to be a bug in `3.0.0.M5`.

Comment: Wow! Been struggling with this rare issue for a whole day now. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a savior. Had been struggling all the day. Thank you so much.